# Disable log out automatically after come back from bank payment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have asp.net web page with dot net 4.0 and i make my login page with asp.net login control, when the user login to my site and wants to go to payment page and set the data, then press pay button and come back to my site, my web page log-out him automatically after redirecting to main page of my site. 
how can i avoid automatically log-out?

```
//my code for payment button:  
PaymentGatewayImplService bpService = new PaymentGatewayImplService();
result = bpService.bpPayRequest(terminalId, UserName,
PassWord,
basketID*1000+tryForPayment,
Int64.Parse(GetPrice()),
PayDateTextBox,
PayTimeTextBox, "",
"www.sample.com/inpay.aspx",
0);

//my code in inpay.aspx load form:
RefIdLabel.Text = Request.Params["RefId"];  
ResCodeLabel.Text = Request.Params["ResCode"];  
SaleOrderIdLabel.Text = Request.Params["SaleOrderId"];  
SaleReferenceIdLabel.Text = Request.Params["SaleReferenceId"];
```

in inpay.aspx my site logout automatically.....

Comment: Cookies, session IDs, etc.

Comment: thanks, but i'm new in asp.net.can u explain it more? ;)

Comment: Please show us the relevant code

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that performs a logout

Comment: Do you know that you can run http://fiddler2.com/ to see what requests are sent? Try that and see if you find strange requests etc. The authentication cookie should be the same for both requests before the payment and after.

Comment: u mean maybe cookies change before and after paymeny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need to implement Forms Authentication into your site.  Here is a simple example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: **_thank a lot for your reasons :)_**. in my web config i used enableCrossAppRedirects="true" and it mean the cookies will be clean when page redirect to another page.thank you for reply :D follow these **links**:[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.enablecrossappredirects.aspx)